# Getting a RecyclerView crash in production - java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Inconsistency detected

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I'm getting a mysterious crash, related to RecyclerView. It appeared in production and I can't reproduce it. It seems to occur very rarely and for some reason mostly on Samsung devices.

Here is part of the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:4 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{39df388 VFED.V... ......ID 0,85-720,986 #7f0900c5 app:id/daily_tasks_recycler_view}, adapter:com.goaldriven.ui.dailytasks.DailyTaskAdapter@da45121, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@34c946, context:com.goaldriven.MainActivity@c4df606

androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6183)
```

This is the code where I'm updating the ArrayList that's used by the adapter and then calling notifyDataSetChanged():

```
public void loadDailyTasksFrom(LocalDate date, OnDailyTasksLoadedListener onDailyTasksLoadedListener) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        if (backupHelper.isBackingUp()) {
            return;
        }
        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getContext(), AppDatabase.class, "app-database").build();
        DailyTaskDao dailyTaskDao = db.dailyTaskDao();
        dailyTasks.clear();
        String dateSqlFormatted = String.format("%04d-%02d-%02d", date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(), date.getDayOfMonth());
        for (DailyTaskEntity dailyTaskEntity : dailyTaskDao.getDailyTasksFrom(dateSqlFormatted)) {
            dailyTasks.add(DailyTask.fromEntity(dailyTaskEntity));
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper());
        handler.post(() -> {
            selectedDate = date;
            updateHintState();
            dailyTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (onDailyTasksLoadedListener != null)
                onDailyTasksLoadedListener.loaded();
        });
        db.close();
    }).start();
}
```

I'm pretty new to android development and I don't even know if this is the right way of updating RecyclerView data. Can you guys spot something obvious that may be causing this crash?

I can also provide the adapter code itself but I think it's irrelevant since it's a pretty standard adapter, populating a few text views.

Thank you in advance!